Why prinnting HttpURLConnection request properties one of that is not present?
I'm using the above java code in order to connect to external server.
This is the code:
URL url = new URL("api-url");
HttpURLConnection hpcon = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
byte[] authBytes = grantprovider.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
String grant_encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(authBytes);
hpcon.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + grant_encoded);
hpcon.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
hpcon.setRequestMethod("POST");
hpcon.setDoInput(true);
hpcon.setDoOutput(true);
hpcon.setUseCaches(false);
Map<String, java.util.List<String>> map = hpcon.getRequestProperties();
for (Map.Entry<String, java.util.List<String>> entry : map.entrySet())
{
    System.out.println("Key : " + entry.getKey() + " ,Value : " + entry.getValue());
}
Map<String, java.util.List<String>> hdrs = hpcon.getHeaderFields();
Set<String> hdrKeys = hdrs.keySet();
for (String k : hdrKeys) {
   System.out.println("Property Key: " + k + " - Property Value: " + hdrs.get(k));
}
for (Map.Entry<String, java.util.List<String>> entries : hpcon.getRequestProperties().entrySet()) {
   String values = "";
   for (String value : entries.getValue()) {
       values += value + ",";
   }
   System.out.println("Request - " + entries.getKey() + " - " +  values );
}
String postData = "grant_type=client_credentials";
try(OutputStream os = hpcon.getOutputStream()) {
   byte[] input = postData.getBytes("utf-8");
   os.write(input, 0, input.length);
}
hpcon.connect();

When I print request properties, why, in one of the ways indicated above, doesn't the Authorization property appear?

This is because your java.net.HttpURLConnection is effectively a sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection and the sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection filters out several request properties for security reasons:
List of the headers

    // the following http request headers should NOT have their values
    // returned for security reasons.
    private static final String[] EXCLUDE_HEADERS = {
            "Proxy-Authorization",
            "Authorization"
    };


Filtering code in getRequestProperties():

    public Map<String, List<String>> getRequestProperties() {
        // ...
            if (setUserCookies) {
                return requests.getHeaders(EXCLUDE_HEADERS);
            }
    }



Thank you.
So is there no way to be sure this property is taken and read its value?

@stefanoerrani no, you cannot verify that you did set this property. The only way to verify that the property was set is to make the request to the protected resource. If the request was accepted you did set the property correctly.
